# Modify SWF after decompiling

Tags: flash

Flash Programming is not the programming language in which write code daily.However I need to modify the behaviour of an `swf` application.I found an online decompilier which gave me the `as` files and I didn't have troubles in understanding the code.However I don't know how to rebuild the as file to obtain a new `swf` after I modified the sources.I found on Internet free tools,like `FlashDevelop` which seems to do this job but I'm stack in understanding how to rebuild the swf.My sources are simple scripts ( no classes ) which seems to be related.Any help is apreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the Macromedia Flash application you will need to publish your solution. This will generate an additional file to your .fla with the file extension .swf.

You already have your working file (the .fla) and you need to generate your output file (.swf). Please visit the link below for a video explanation of swf's.

[.fla's and .swf's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIMhxyeJcT8)